# Docker+Eclipse in Windows 10 Setup & Configuration: Full Procedure

Tags: docker, eclipse

I have tried to run my first ever program in Docker, while using Eclipse for (C++) development. Unfortunately, many hours of internet searches led to nothing but confusion (mixed with desperation), endless errors, tons of manuals that skip steps and/or assume you're already familiar with how all of it works.

I have never used Docker before and only installed the Docker Desktop and downloaded Alpine Linux image. I haven't done anything else with it so far (because I was unable to).

OS: Windows 10 (21H2 Build 19044.2486)
Eclipse: Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0) - newest as of publishing this
Docker Desktop: v4.25.2 - newest as of publishing this

Things I have achieved so far are not particularly plentiful:

In eclipse, I have installed Docker Tooling, and I got to see the "Docker Explorer" window. I need a new connection, so I click to create a connection and see this:
[image]

Here, if I click on "Search" next to supposed Connection Name, I'm given an error and prompted to provide path to docker files:
[image]

The path is correct, all the binaries are there:
[image]

Unfortunately, upon applying and closing the window with path, I'm presented with an error: Unable to search for Docker Machines as paths to the executables are invalid.

At this point, I have no idea what to do. The only relevant information I found is that docker-machine.exe has been deprecated a couple of years ago, and that on Mac and Win, one should connect over TCP.

**Question**:

How do I configure Docker and Eclipse together and run my first ever App in a container? Can I have a **full list of steps** I need to do? Let's imagine for the sake of covering everything that I have a clean Windows 10 install, I have installed Docker Desktop and Eclipse (and they both launch without an error; Eclipse has the default GCC configuration) and haven't done anything else. I want to print a C++ "Hello World" in a docker container. How exactly do I go about it?